# Default routing in Zend Framework after defining some routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I've been writing a project since some time and I've used the default routing, the :module\:controller:\:action. 
After some time, I've added some routers to my config like:

```
resources.router.routes.page.route = "page/:slug"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.controller = "pages"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.action = "view"
resources.router.routes.page.defaults.slug = ""
```

But, after that, when I click on some link generated by view URL helper with one of the new routes all other links ignore some of given paramters. Example, I've got route:

```
resources.router.routes.project.route = "project/:slug"
resources.router.routes.project.defaults.module = "projects"
resources.router.routes.project.defaults.controller = "projects"
resources.router.routes.project.defaults.action = "view"
resources.router.routes.project.defaults.slug = ""
```

If I go to a link /project/test then link like this:

```
$this->url(
    array('module' => 'admin', 'action' => 'list-users', 'controller' => 'users')
, null,true
);
```

will point to "/project"

Is there any possibility to maintain the default routing on top of custom routes? Can I add some default router that will work the same as the default one? It's probably something simple but I maybe missed the point. Thanks for all the help.

I've added something like this but with no effect:

```
resources.router.routes.default.route = ":module/:controller/:action"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.controller = "pages"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.action = "view"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.slug = ""
```

Comment: Please define "dont work" - do you get an error, or do the links point to the wrong place?

Comment: Ok, I've added some more info

Comment: If you pass 'default' as the second param to the url helper instead of null does that make any difference?

Comment: Yep, then it works. But Should the default be chosen when I pass null? I really would like to refactor all of those helpers call :-)

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to set your custom routing, you need to get the router component and pass your routes into it.

This is how I did mine in a project I am working on. In your Bootstrap class, you create the following function

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontcontroller');
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $myRoutes = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.ini','production');
    $router->addConfig($myRoutes,'routes');
```

This calls the front controller and gets the router from it. I then pass my routes config into it.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: It's the same as adding it to application.ini via resource. I've trayed both ways, no luck

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the options for url helper are as follows:

```
url($urlOptions, $name, $reset)
```

Therefore, when you set `$name` to `null`, current route (`'project'`) is used. Not event setting `$reset` to `true` will help. Replace `null` with `'default'` and it should work.